# C++ Arrays: Go from 1D to 2D

Tags: c++

I have an array of ints:

```
int a[1];
```

I then want to make the items in `a` be pointers to the next dimension of arrays.

```
a[0] = new int b[3];
```

Would I then be able to use the double bracket indexing?

```
a[0][0] = 1; //Assign 1 to b[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make items in `a` array, then you have to define it that way.

```
int *a[1];
a[0] = new int[3];
```

Or similary

```
int a[1][3];
```

Or

```
int **a;
a = new int *[1];
a[0] = new int[3];
```

But as you you have `c++` tag, you should rather use `std::vector` (or `std::array` in `c++11`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you must make `a` an array of pointers:

```
int *a[1];
```

Comment: I didn't advise it, but rather answered the question. The OP is clearly learning. At some point he will have to learn about raw pointers in order to make sense of all the quirks of templates and polymorphism. This is as good a place to start learning as any.

Comment: No, he won't. You can do templates first. Especially, say, `std::vector`.